# How to return a value in a Go function that panics?

Tags: go, exception, recover

My Go function is expected to return a value, but it may panic when calling a library function. I can use `recover()` to capture this in a deferred call, but how can I return a value in this case?

```
func MyFunc() string{
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            // What do I do to make MyFunc() return a value in case of panic?
        }
    }()
    SomeFuncThatMayPanic()
    return "Normal Return Value"
    // How can I return "ERROR" in case of panic?
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use [named result parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types). Name your return values, and in the deferred function when panic was detected, you can change the values of the return "variables". The changed new values will be returned.

Example:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Returned:", MyFunc())
}

func MyFunc() (ret string) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            ret = fmt.Sprintf("was panic, recovered value: %v", r)
        }
    }()
    panic("test")
    return "Normal Return Value"
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZOSD2QU6VO)):

```
Returned: was panic, recovered value: test
```

This is mentioned in the [**Spec: Defer statements**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> For instance, if the deferred function is a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) and the surrounding function has [named result parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) that are in scope within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters before they are returned.

It is also mentioned in the blog post [**Defer, Panic and Recover**](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover):

> Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.

And also in [**Effective Go: Recover**](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover):

> If `doParse` panics, the recovery block will set the return value to `nil`—deferred functions can modify named return values.

Comment: I was interested in **what would be returned if there were no named return values**. Playing with your playground, it looks like it's the zero value of the type

Comment: @KyleChadha Yes, if results are unnamed and a `return` statement is not reached (e.g. due to a panic), the zero values of the result types are returned. This is detailed in [Why can a normal return hide a panic that a named return correctly provides to the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461527/why-can-a-normal-return-hide-a-panic-that-a-named-return-correctly-provides-to-t/59461751#59461751)

Answer (score 2):

Using the example in icza's answer, and if you wonder what happens **if you recover from the panic but don't assign the value for the named return**, like this:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Returned:", MyFunc()) // false
}

func MyFunc() (ret bool) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
        }
    }()
    panic("test")
    return true
}
```

The function **will return the zero value** of the specified return type.

Run the example in the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/13s9ty45cL6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use named parameter like this:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Returned:", MyFunc())
}

func MyFunc() (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err=convertRecoverToError(r)
        }
    }()
    panic("test")
    return nil
}

func ConvertRecoverToError(r interface{}) error {
    switch x := r.(type) {
    case string:
        return errors.New(x)
    case error:
        return x
    default:
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprint(x))
    }
}
```