# Why I get 0 and 1 in the following golang code example with defer

Tags: go, defer-keyword

Call to defer produces different results for variables declared in two different ways

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func c(i int) int {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return i
}

func c1() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return i
}

func c2() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return 2
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(c(0)) // Prints 0
    fmt.Println(c1()) // Prints 1
    fmt.Println(c2()) // Prints 3 Thank you icza
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gfnnCZ--DkH

Comment: Thanks to Johan Brandhorst from #general@golang slack for the reference https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements "That is, if the surrounding function returns through an explicit return statement, deferred functions are executed after any result parameters are set by that return statement but before the function returns to its caller"

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements *"if the surrounding function returns through an explicit return statement, deferred functions are executed **after** any result parameters are set by that return statement but **before** the function returns to its caller."* ... *"if the deferred function is a function literal and the surrounding function has named result parameters that are in scope within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters **before** they are returned."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first example `i` is an (incoming) parameter. At the `return` statement the return value is evaluated, and the deferred function runs after this, and incrementing `i` in that has no effect on the return value.

In the second example `i` is the name of the result parameter. At the `return` statement you explicitly return the value `i`, which is then assigned to the return value `i` (this is a no-op). But deferred functions are allowed to modify the values of the return "variables", and if they do so, that will have an effect on the actual returned values.

This becomes clearer if we add another example:

```
func c2() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return 2
}
```

This function will return `3`, because the `return 2` statement will assign `2` to `i`, then the deferred function will increment this, and so the return value will be `3`. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zdc1NkVqANm). Relevant part from the [Spec: Return statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)

> A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

In general, if a function (or method) has named result parameters, the return values will always be the values of those variables, but must not forget that a `return` statement may assign new values to these result paramteters, and they may be modified by deferred functions *after* a `return` statement.

This is mentioned in the [**Spec: Defer statements**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> For instance, if the deferred function is a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) and the surrounding function has [named result parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) that are in scope within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters before they are returned.

It is also mentioned in the blog post [**Defer, Panic and Recover**](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover):

> Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.

And also in [**Effective Go: Recover**](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover):

> If `doParse` panics, the recovery block will set the return value to `nil`—deferred functions can modify named return values.

See related question: [How to return a value in a Go function that panics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167282/how-to-return-a-value-in-a-go-function-that-panics/33167433#33167433)