# Why can a normal return hide a panic that a named return correctly provides to the caller?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func catch(err *error) {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        *err = fmt.Errorf("recovered panic: %v", r)
    }
}

func panicIf42(n int) {
    if n == 42 {
        panic("42!")
    }
}

func NormalReturns(n int) error {
    var err error
    defer catch(&err)
    panicIf42(n)
    return err
}

func NamedReturns(n int) (err error) {
    defer catch(&err)
    panicIf42(n)
    return
}

func main() {
    err := NamedReturns(42)
    log.Printf("NamedReturns error: %v", err)
    err = NormalReturns(42)
    log.Printf("NormalReturns error: %v", err)
}
```

output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 NamedReturns error: recovered panic: 42!
2009/11/10 23:00:00 NormalReturns error: <nil>
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/0e0Vhz7fe4E)

NormalReturns returns a nil error, but I would expect both NamedReturns and NormalReturns to return a non-nil error.

I thought named returns was just a code readability feature that declares and initializes returns for you, but it seems there's more to it. What am I missing?

Comment: I'll let someone who can speak from specification rather than intuition add a proper answer, but my intuition is that the `defer` is executed after `return err` already happened; so changing `err` no longer has any effect -- the copy to be returned was already copied to the stack, so modifying the local variable you declared with `var err error` no longer does anything useful. Whereas in the named-return case, `&err` refers to the copy on the stack.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy exactly. the behavior is `Deferred function calls are executed in Last In First Out order after the surrounding function returns.`

Comment: Nothing _hides_ a panic. It's just that to store the recovered value, you need a named return variable.

Answer (score 5):

> I thought named returns was just a code readability feature that declares and initializes returns for you, but it seems there's more to it. What am I missing?

If you name the result parameters, their actual value at the time of returning to the caller will determine the returned values. Meaning you can change their values like other local variables, and if the expression list of the `return` statement is empty, their last assigned values will be used. Also if there are deferred functions, they can modify the values of the named result parameters *after* the `return` statement and *before* the function returns to its caller, and those modifications will be preserved. It also allows to modify return values in case of a panic, see [How to return a value in a Go function that panics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167282/how-to-return-a-value-in-a-go-function-that-panics/33167433#33167433)

[Spec: Return statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)

> Regardless of how they [the  return values] are declared, all the result values are initialized to the [zero values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for their type upon entry to the function. A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

And [Spec: Defer statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)

> For instance, if the deferred function is a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) and the surrounding function has [named result parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) that are in scope within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters before they are returned.

In `NormalReturns()`: The return value is initialized to its zero value (which is `nil` for all interface types, including the builtin [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) type), **and since the `return` statement is not reached (due to a panic in `panicIf42()`), it will stay `nil`**. It doesn't matter if the local variable `err` is changed, that is not the result variable. It's just an ordinary variable. It will have no effect on the value returned

In general, if a function does not have named result variables, and if this function does not reach a `return` statement (e.g. due to a panic), it cannot have return values other than (meaning different from) the zero values of the result types.

In `NamedReturns()` the deferred `catch()` will modify the named result variable `err`. The changes are "preserved": whatever the named result variables hold will be returned when the function ends (which happens after calling deferred functions, if there are any). So even though the `return` statement is not reached here either, the `catch()` function changes the `err` result variable, and whatever is assigned to it will be used as the value returned.

More on the topic:

[Go blog: Defer, Panic and Recover:](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

> Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.

And also in [Effective Go: Recover:](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover)

> If `doParse` panics, the recovery block will set the return value to `nil`—deferred functions can modify named return values.

Comment: that did not help in understanding the actual behavior. Charles Duffy explanations kind of makes sense, however it seems like there is subtle implementation difference that remains hard to figure out.

Comment: @mh-cbon Added more details.

Comment: definitely helped. To rephrase, `NormalReturns` does not return the locally defined `err` variable because it does not reach the return statement which would copy it to the result values, it instead returns the zero values because the panic broke the flow. However, in `NamedReturns` when the return happens, because this is a named variable, it returns that variable value, which can be modified by the defer etc. thank you

Comment: @mh-cbon Yes, I also highlighted that part in my answer.

Comment: @icza i may be misreading something here, but the bold part and the the paragraph after it seem to suggest that if the return statement was reached the deferred function has the ability to modify the returned value even though it's not a named result parameter? Is that actually the case?

Comment: @mkopriva That paragraph tells that if the return parameters are not named and a `return` is not reached, the values actually returned will always be the zero values (the deferred functions can't modify something unnamed).

Comment: @icza ah yes, my bad, I did indeed misunderstood the point there. Thanks.

Comment: playing with  https://play.golang.org/p/Iz-omlTTPu0 following mkopriva comment, and `the deferred function may access and modify the result parameters before they are returned` poorly makes sense anymore..  I suggest to slightly modify that quotes to use **named result parameters**. or to quote more of it `For instance, if the deferred function is a function literal and the surrounding function has named result parameters that are in scope within the literal...`

Comment: @mh-cbon Extended the quote.