# Deferred function returns nil value after panic

Tags: go

I am writing a function & its unit test using testing package in go. I am trying to return error(nil if no panic) from the function if it panics for some reason. Problem is, For some reason deferred function always returns nil value as error

code.go

```
func SomeFunction() error{

err := error(nil)
defer func() error {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        err = errors.New("SomeFunction: panicked!")
    }
    fmt.Println(err==nil) 
    return err
}()
//code that may panic
panic("test")
return err
}
```

code_test.go

```
func TestSomefunction(t *testing.T){
  err := SomeFunction()
  fmt.Println(err)
 }
```

Output:

```
false
<nil>
```

I am calling panic explicitly to check the test that I am writing. On running `go test` the output suggests that err is not nil inside the deferred section. But it is returning nil to the test function. I am definitely missing something here.

Comment: Neither `err` nor the return value from the defered function has any effect on the value returned by `SomeFunction`.

Comment: I think I asked too soon. Modifying the return value from just  `error` to `(err error)` helped somehow and it works as expected. I'm new to go so not sure why this worked.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Not really. Because a quick glance suggests that the answer you linked says that this code should work( with my earlier comment's modification). Thanks!

Comment: @PaulHankin Sorry, I don't really get what you said. Isn't  `err`/<return value from deferred function> what SomeFunction returns?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Oh right! you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: see also [icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59461751/1256452) to [Why can a normal return hide a panic that a named return correctly provides to the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59461527/1256452)

This is essentially a duplicate of [How to return a value in a Go function that panics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33167282/1256452)  However, the answer to that question just says that you must use a named return value, without explaining *why* you must use a named return value.

I've never found the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) here particularly clear myself.  The description of [return statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) mentions three ways to return values from a function with a result type,<sup>1</sup> but does not say anything explicit about panic and recover here.  The rest is left to the section titled [Handling panics](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics):

> While executing a function `F`, an explicit call to panic or a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) terminates the execution of `F`. Any functions deferred ... [mostly snipped as not relevant here]. This termination sequence is called *panicking*.
>
> [snippage]
>
> The `recover` function allows a program to manage behavior of a panicking goroutine. Suppose a function `G` defers a function `D` that calls recover and a panic occurs in a function on the same goroutine in which `G` is executing. When the running of deferred functions reaches `D`, the return value of `D`'s call to `recover` will be the value passed to the call of `panic`.

What all of this verbiage tells us is that we have to put the call to `recover` inside a function that we call using `defer`.  That part is clear enough, and you've done it in your own code:

> ```golang
> defer func() error {
>     if r := recover(); r != nil {
>         err = errors.New("SomeFunction: panicked!")
>     }
>     fmt.Println(err==nil) 
>     return err
> }()
> ```

Your deferred function—technically a closure—has a return value of type `error`, but *this return value is discarded* because deferred functions are simply called with the values discarded (always).  You might as well have written your closure to return nothing; this would function exactly the same way.

But your closure *also* captures the outer variable named `err`, and assigns to it.  Your goal here is clear enough, I think: **you wanted this to be the return value from the function containing the closure**.  Alas, it won't be.

Let's return to the description of `panic`-and-`recover` now:

> If `D` returns normally, without starting a new panic, the panicking sequence stops. In that case, the state of functions called between `G` and the call to panic is discarded, and normal execution resumes.

This too is a bit confusing.  Let's think about it a moment.  The final statement here is that *normal execution resumes*.  But `recover` got called only because *deferred functions were being run*.  So *normal execution*, at this point, is already into the sequence of handling `defer`s, in reverse order, popping them off the stack of `defer`s for this particular function.  In other words, **we're already well in the middle of returning from function `G`** (the one that calls `panic`).

There's one more statement left here before the spec goes into its own example:

> Any functions deferred by `G` before `D` are then run and `G`'s execution terminates by returning to its caller.

This is just telling us that, indeed, the remaining `defer`s get popped off the stack, one by one, and run.  Function `G` is, in other words, still in the middle of returning normally (no longer panicking).

---

The phrase *a function with a result type* simply means a function that returns some value(s), as opposed to, e.g., `func f(args) { ... }` which returns no values.

---

#### What's missing here from the spec's example and/or return-value description

I mentioned above that the return statement description talked about three ways to return a value from a function:

1. You can use a `return` statement with an expression list.
2. You can use a `return` statement that returns a multi-valued function.
3. You can have a function with named return values.

This third method is special.  The spec doesn't come right out and *say* so, but we can *infer* it, because a `return` with no expressions simply returns the values that are in the variables *and the variables can be modified in deferred closures*.

This last part is not described *here* but rather in the section on [defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements).  Nonetheless, it is true.  Since the deferred closure *can* modify the return value, that's how we do it.  That's true for a deferred function that calls `recover` as well.  A return statement *without values*, such as:

```
func f() (a int, b string) {
    a = 42
    b = "what is six times nine"
    return
}
```

sets `a` and `b` and then returns, and a `return` *with values:*

```
func f() (a int, b string) {
    return 42, "what is six times nine"
}
```

does exactly the same things.  That is, first we assign, then we return.  The return values can then be overridden by `defer`s.  If one of the deferred calls happens to catch a `panic` by calling `recover`, *and* that deferred call is to a closure that *modifies the variable*, that modification happens *after the assignment* and therefore changes the value of the variable, so that the `return` returns the newly assigned value.

If we don't use a *named return variable*, though, there is no variable to modify.  So for a `recover` to *change* a return value, the only possible method is to use a named return variable.